# Not able to Insert random values into a vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying out a simple vector code which I saw on Pluralsight, for some reason the code exits after executing not showing any output, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(0);
    int n=5;
    int c=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int x=(int)rand();
        for(auto m=begin(v);m!=end(v);m++)
        {
            cout<<"hello";
            if(*m < x)
            {
                v.insert(m, x);
                c=0;
            }
            if(c==1)
                v.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    cout<<"HLLO";
    for(int j : v)
        cout<<j<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I didnt get any output so i tried printing hello to see if the inner for loop is being executed but for some reason it directly exits without printing anything
:'(

Comment: What do you expect the size of `v` to be before you've inserted anything?

Comment: I thought it was an issue with the vector being empty so i added an element before i started using it

Comment: @FredLarson is it because i am using a pointer to iterate and not an integer?

Comment: Once you insert, you invalidate the iterators. You likely need to `break;` after inserting. But you haven't stated the purpose of the code, so it's difficult to know what to suggest.

Comment: the idea of the code in the video was to show the time difference between list and vectors when you  try to comb through its elements, what i am trying to do is create a random number and insert it into the vector such that its in ascending order, the first loop is to generate the random numbers and the second loop is to insert it or push it if its greater than all the elements. Also what does invalidating an iterator mean im really new to this :')

Comment: `std::vector` is a data structure that grows as elements are added. To facilitate this growth, it often needs to reallocate its memory. This may mean moving the vector data to a completely different piece of memory. Iterators are like pointers, so an iterator obtained before insertion may point into a memory allocation that is no longer valid.